# Up to date solution to expose C# .net assemblies to C++

Tags: c#, c++, com, c++-cli, wrapper

I have C++ Qt application together with a lot of .net C# assemblies, that I would need to use in the C++. Before doing any research I was expecting there is existing solution to generate C++/CLI wrapper DLL for usage in pure C++ app, but to my surprise I wasn't able to find anything except [SharpCpp](https://github.com/m039/SharpCpp), but that's just experiment.
As the amount of classes that need to be exposed might be pretty extensive, I was looking for as much as automatic solution possible ( like what I'm used to when wrapping C++ for Python using shiboken)

As far as I can tell my possibilities are (as just compiling the app with /clr is not an option):

- Manually write C++/CLI bridge DLLs, but this could take a lot of time.
- use COM, but that would also mean a need to implement the COM exposure to all C# assemblies also. Or is there any automated solution?
- use CLR Hosting. Not an option without automatic generation of the wrapper also.
- try using something like [Alter-Native](https://alexalbala.github.io/Alter-Native/) or [cs2cpp](https://github.com/ASDAlexander77/cs2cpp), but I don't know how much production ready this is.

So I was wondering, if someone was facing similar problem, and what turned out to be the best, and most maintainable solution.

Comment: I would forget about C++/CLI. Don't know about altenative/cs2cpp. Building a COM API is the most obvious way to expose anything to another language on Windows. But as you say, if the C# was written w/o interop in mind, you'll have to add a COM C# layer to the existing C# classes. That could be partially automated but there's nothing out of the box, and there is no 1-1 mapping, some types or constructs won't go through easily (generics, etc.). It really depends on how your C# is written. Note there's also corert: https://github.com/dotnet/corert

Comment: You don't need to implement COM exposure for ALL of your assemblies. You just need it for the ones you directly call from C++. Think about it. If I write a C# component to be called via COM, I will be using a whole bunch of the .NET eco-system. All those items aren't exposed to COM. Only things you directly call need to be exposed. If you have an object and it has a property that is a class in another assembly, you are probably going to have to make that other assembly COM aware/visible too. You can make whole assemblies [ComVisible(true)], but in general I don't recommend that.